# Screen tearing in Firefox when using Sawfish

Tags: xorg, firefox, tearing, sawfish

When using the Sawfish window manager, there is [screen tearing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing) in videos in Firefox. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, run a [compositor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositing_window_manager) (these provide off-screen buffers for each window) alongside your non-compositing window manager. Compton seems to do the trick.

Install the needed packages and add this to `.gnomerc`:

```
# To get tearing-free video in Firefox
hsetroot -solid '#000000'
compton --backend glx &             # Worked for me in Ubuntu 16.04
compton --backend xr_glx_hybrid &   # Works for me in Ubuntu 18.04
```

The `hsetroot` line is needed if the [background goes gray](https://superuser.com/questions/786734/compton-background-color).

My setup:
Software: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS, Firefox 59.0.1, Sawfish 1.11, and Compton 0.1~beta2.
Graphics: `RADEON(0): Chipset: "CAICOS" (ChipID = 0x6779)`

Tearing tests:

- [4k vsync test 60fps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gmHaa5pvpVc)
- [tearing test @29.97 fps (1080p)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xkNy9gfKOg)
- [Web browser "VSYNC synchronization" tester](https://www.vsynctester.com/)

More information:

- [How to enable transparency](http://sawfish.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_enable_transparency) (discusses compositors for Sawfish)
- [Howto: Using Compton for tear-free compositing on XFCE or LXDE](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2144468)
- [1134077 - HTML5 video tearing in full-screen mode on mutter (GNOME) due to vsync problem and compositor bypass](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1134077) (discussion about Firefox and compositing)

Some related questions:

- [Optimus laptop - Chopping and stuttering videos with Intel onboard graphics and screen tearing with Nvidia graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/836276/optimus-laptop-chopping-and-stuttering-videos-with-intel-onboard-graphics-and/840376#840376)
- [How do I remove screen tearing in 16.04 with nvidia GTX 960 M?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760712/how-do-i-remove-screen-tearing-in-16-04-with-nvidia-gtx-960-m)